# Recibiendo dos notificaciones y visualizando sólo los datos de la última

Tags: push-notification, notificaciones

El caso es que llevo bastante tiempo con este problema y no encuentro la solución por ningún sitio.

Un servidor remoto envía dos notificaciones con diferentes títulos, datos y diferente "topic".
En mi App (en primer plano) recibo correctamente las dos notificaciones desde el servidor remoto y se visualizan correctamente en la barra de notificaciones.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String METODO="onMessageReceived";
        Log.e("METODO",CLASE+"."+METODO);

    
        int notificationId_diario = 123456789; // ID notification
        int notificationId_resultado = 987654321; // ID notification

        Intent notificationIntent;

        if(MainActivity.isAppRunning){

            // Qué hacemos si la aplicación está en primer plano
            notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        }

        // Recuperamos los datos de la notificación
        String titulo=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String mensaje=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.e("NOTIFICACION","TITULO: "+titulo);
        Log.e("NOTIFICACION","MENSAJE: "+mensaje);

        notificationIntent.addFlags(
//                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
//                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
//                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        );

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Configuramos la notificación para Android Oreo o superior
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupChannels();
        }
    
        Log.e("DATA","EXISTE: "+(remoteMessage.getData()!=null));
        if(remoteMessage.getData()!=null) {
            // Comprobamos el contenido de los datos de la notificación
            String de=remoteMessage.getFrom();
            
            if(de.contains("Resultado")) {
                String titulo2 = remoteMessage.getData().get("TITULO");
                String resultado = remoteMessage.getData().get("MENSAJE");
                Log.e("DATOS RESULTADO","TITULO: "+titulo2);
                Log.e("DATOS RESULTADO","MENSAJE: "+resultado);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("TITULO", titulo2);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("MENSAJE",resultado);
        
                final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
//                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
//                        0
                );
        
        showNotification(titulo, mensaje, pendingIntent, notificationId_resultado);
            }else if(de.contains("Diario")){
                String titulo2=remoteMessage.getData().get("TITULO");
                String bote=remoteMessage.getData().get("MENSAJE");
                Log.e("DATOS DIARIO","TITULO: "+titulo2);
                Log.e("DATOS DIARIO","MENSAJE: "+bote);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("TITULO", titulo2);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("MENSAJE",bote);
        
                final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
//                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
//                        0
                );
        
        showNotification(titulo, mensaje, pendingIntent, notificationId_diario);
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay información adiccional", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String text, PendingIntent pendingIntent,int notificationId) {
        String METODO="showNotification";
        Log.e("METODO",CLASE+"."+METODO);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text)) //ditto
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Independientemente de la notificación que abra, los datos que veo en la pantalla son los de la última notificación recibida.
He jugado con los "Flags" tanto del Intent como los del PendingInten y no he conseguido solución.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias

Answer (score 4):

Un poco tarde la respuesta pero de todas maneras me gustaría comentarte:

En la parte que creas el *PendingIntent* estas pasando siempre el mismo *requestCode*.

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
        "AQUI" 0, 
        notificationIntent,                      
        YOURFLAGS);
```

Puedes probar de crear un método que retorne un random:

```
private int generateRequestCodeRandom() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt();
}
```

Y asignarlo a tu *PendingIntent* así:

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
        generateRequestCodeRandom(), 
        notificationIntent,                      
        YOURFLAGS);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta respuesta me fue muy util